Sea monster attacking a city
I watched a film on TV in the mid 80s that I'm struggling to identify through Google-fu. 
Not sure when it was made but I remember thinking the special effects were quite good so I'd guess it must have been early to mid eighties, possibly late seventies. Can't really remember anything about the cast.
It was about a big Godzilla-esque monster that was attacking a US city. Most of the movie was about their efforts to capture it/stop it. I think it was set somewhere in California; it was definitely somewhere with a coastline. 
I remember the ending quite well. Eventually they trapped the monster in a pit/aquarium they'd made. It then started crying out for its mummy and a massive foot came down smashing through the cage which freed the monster. You'd gone through the whole film thinking the monster was enormous but it turns out it was just a baby and the mother was several orders of magnitude bigger. It ended with them both swimming off in to the sunset.

The movie Gorgo comes to mind, though it is set in London and has even been touted as "the British Godzilla", it has a very similar premise to what you described, maybe it helps even if it's not the one.

@Ghoti and Chips It's probably the right movie, you should post it as an answer.

@Ghoti and Chips Yeah that's the one. Cheers!

The movie Gorgo (1961) comes to mind, though it is set in London and has even been touted as "the British Godzilla".


The film focuses on Gorgo, an ancient large sea monster brought back to London for exploitation, and his even larger mother, who rampages across London to search for him. The effects were complex and are well respected by special effects artists and fans. The film is also sometimes praised for its innovative ending.

